# How to make EEGlab in Matlab read and analyze Audacity audio files

Tags: matlab

My EEG unit has BNC output at the back where the signal is directly fed to an ADC and into Audacity. How can I make EEGLab in Matlab read and analyze the frequency spectrum of the file? What format must I export it at Audacity to make it compatible with EEGLab?